# SubCatalog not displaying in the django admin page

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django application that has catalog which is the parent for subcatalog and the products will be mapped along the subcatalog. I am posting my code below, please help.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class SubCatalog(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name            

class Product(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog)
    subcatalog = models.ForeignKey(SubCatalog)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='product_photo', blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    price_in_ksh = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Have you register `SubCatalog` in `admin.py`?

Comment: @Railslide i always mess with the smallest of things thanks it is now displaying

Comment: @Railside I have an additional question how can i edit the above code so that when i am registering a product and i select the catalog e.g men's collection the subcatalog will only display the subcatalog for the men's collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register `SubCatalog` in your app `admin.py`:

```
admin.site.register(SubCatalog)
```